# AT command to delete received messages using TC35i modem

Tags: sms, at-command, modem

I am trying to add a delete all stored messages function to my Java program. I have tried

```
AT+CMGD=all
AT+CMGD=del all
AT+CMGD=1,4
AT+CMGD=1.4
```

I cannot find the answer in the AT command sheet so i'm wondering if there even is a delete all command for the TC35i.

I use Hyperterminal for testing commands (no need to provide code)

I can delete individuel messages using the usual `AT+CMGD=<index>`

Comment: Regarding the syntax of AT commands: strings shall **always** be enclosed in double quotes (e.g. `AT+CMGD="ALL"`), and parameters shall only be separated by comma (e.g. `AT+CMGD=1,4`). If you read chapter 5 in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) you will learn this and much more.

Comment: Regarding the AT+CMGD command, it only takes numeric arguments on both PDU and TEXT mode (unlike AT+CMGL). Read the [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) specification for the general definition of the command as a supplement to the manufacturer specific documentation (which always is the authoritative reference).

Answer (score 1):

I found the manual from http://www.comat.ch/unitronics/download/manual/TC35i%20AT%20Commands.pdf

From that, it does not support to delete all SMS with one AT. Since you program in JAVA, maybe you can make a loop to delete one by one.

And, in latest standard, **AT+CMGD=1,4** shall be the AT you expected.